# cloning my ubuntu image to HDD alongside win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I bought a new laptop with win 10 pre-installed. Now I want my Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my old laptop HDD to be cloned and installed on the new HDD alongside win 10.
So far I was able to run Ubuntu from the external HDD. I installed the new drivers, disabled secure boot, ... Bottom line it Ubuntu runs smoothly from the old HDD mounted on the new laptop through USB/sSATA port.
I partitioned the new HDD already.
How can I do that?
Also. My old version of Ubuntu was installed alongside win7 so GRUB2 is installed somewhere. Will it be reinstalled on the new HHD? And if so, would it work for dual booting?
Thanks,
Marcello

Comment: Not recommended. Windows 10 will be UEFI, and old Ubuntu is probably BIOS with MBR. And UEFI has gpt partitioning so you cannot easily clone a MBR partition to gpt. Better to do new install in UEFI mode and copy /home and/or data into new install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Be sure to use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partition and reboot immediately. Then use gparted or installer to create partitions.

Comment: @oldfred: convert to answer and drop me a note so I can upvote!  That is indeed the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended.

Windows 10 will be UEFI, and old Ubuntu is probably BIOS with MBR.

And UEFI has gpt partitioning so you cannot easily clone a MBR partition to gpt. Better to do new install in UEFI mode and copy /home and/or data into new install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Be sure to use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partition and reboot immediately. Then use gparted or installer to create partitions. Also make sure Windows fast startup  or always on hibernation is turned off.